# Recompressing standalone vmlinux ELF file

Tags: linux, elf, bootable

I have a **vmlinux** file with no source code, header files or any other peripherals.

What's the easiest way to convert it into a bootable zImage?

Comment: It's not currently in front of me, but as I remember it's not stripped, has 40~ sections I think. Need any specific information?

Comment: From the [lkml](http://lkml.iu.edu/hypermail/linux/kernel/9909.3/0625.html): *Be warned that you can't boot directly a vmlinux file, because it relies on some work done in the boot image* and *The zImage contain `bootsect.o` + `setup.o` + `misc.o` + `piggy.o`; `piggy.o` contain the gzipped vmlinux file in its data section (ELF)*. Without those additional routines, you don't have a bootable image.

Comment: Yes, my goal is to generate that vmlinuz/zImage file that contains that sections